# SonarQube webhook sending empty JSON after build

Tags: sonarqube, devops, sonarqube-ops

I am working on SonarQube integration with our project management application. For that, I have to use [SonarQube web hooks](https://docs.sonarqube.org/display/SONAR/Webhooks) to trigger application.

I already set the hook and everything but after every build Sonar is sending empty JSON in POST body.

How to configure data and everything to get a proper response from hook.

[image]

Comment: SonarQube never sends webhook payloads with empty JSON. The minimal document contains at least a few fields that can't have null values. I suggest to double-check your web server or potential intermediary proxies.

Comment: Yes, @SimonBrandhof-SonarSource are right. I was checking post body instead of payload. thank you very much. your comment helps me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As discussed the JSON payload is correctly sent in the POST HTTP request.